# Windows embedded CE 6.0 and Odbc

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio, odbc, windows-ce

I am writing an application to run on a windows embedded ce 6.0.
the application needs to have access to a sql database and insert records into it.
My boss said i have to use Odbc commands, but so far i haven't seen proof that windows embedded ce 6.0 supports Odbc at all. 
Can someone confirm that for me please before I go to my boss and humiliate myself in case I am wrong :p?
and In case i cannot use Odbc: is there any alternative?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Compact Framework has no support for ODBC.  What type of database do you need to connect with?  Many ([SQL Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient%28v=vs.90%29.aspx), [Oracle](http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/oracle/), [MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/6.0.html), [SQLite](http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/), etc) have ADO.NET Providers

[Here's an example for using the SQL Server provider](http://community.opennetcf.com/articles/cf/archive/2007/09/20/developing-connected-smart-device-application-with-sqlclient.aspx).

Comment: I need to connect to sql server database (remotely)

Comment: The System.Data.SqlClient (see the link in the answer) is the way to go.

Comment: Okay! thank you, I'll check with my boss and ask him why he was choosing Odbc.

Comment: The example you gave is for windows mobile 6.0 which is different from windows embedded ce 6.0

Comment: For what you're doing, no it's not.  The process for connecting to a SQL Server from the Compact Framework is the same for all versions of Windows CE (well, except Windows Phone).

Comment: Ok! So I am using SqlClent now but I am getting an error message every time I attempt to open The SqlConnection: can't find pinvoke dll 'dbnetlib.dll' Any ideas on how to fix that!

Answer (score 0):

Windows CE 6.0 does not support ODBC:

> http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sqlce/thread/ed42734d-1594-4fe0-90ca-9e55771421af
>
> No, there’s no such API. ODBC is not supported on CE and OLEDB driver
>   is not available.

... or ...

> http://docs.oracle.com/html/B10100_01/wnovw.htm
>
> Windows CE does not support the ODBC driver manager.

However, one good alternative is the CE variant of standard (VB6 era) ADO, ADOCE:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms834317.aspx

Comment: Thank you, so another question is when I Type the line using System.Data.Odbc; visual studio 2008 is not recognizing Odbc, why is that?

Comment: Note the C# tag in the question

Comment: ADOCE support was dropped long ago, along with the entire set of eVB runtimes.  You cannot use ADOCE from managed code at all.

Comment: Okay! thank you, I'll check with my boss and ask him why he was choosing Odbc